# woocommerce change stock number placement

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change stock info placement. I managed to change it on simple product, however I have no idea how can I make it works for product with variations.

I copied that code to price.php - becouse its the place i would like to have it

```
// Availability
$availability = $product->get_availability();
 if ( $availability['availability'] )

    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_html', '<p style="float:right"  class="stock ' . esc_attr( $availability['class'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $availability['availability'] ) . '</p>', $availability['availability'] );
?> 
 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' ); ?>
```

however as I said it works only for simple product.
The css styling is not the option here ;) 
to make it more clear here's image of what I would like to [achieve](http://sklepogrodniczy.net/images/placement.jpg)